# join or merge or reshape dataframe based on two conditions

Tags: pandas, join, merge, python-3.5

I have two dataframes df and df1 which I want to merge or join.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['lt1', 'lt2','lt3','lt4','lt5','lt6'])
df['date'] = pd.date_range('2016-1-1', periods=5, freq='D')
df
   lt1  lt2  lt3  lt4  lt5  lt6       date
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN 2016-01-01
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN 2016-01-02
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN 2016-01-03
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN 2016-01-04
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN 2016-01-05

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'location': ['lt1','lt3', 'lt6', 'lt1','lt2', 'lt3'], \
                   'date': ['2016-01-1', '2016-01-02','2016-01-1','2016-01-03','2016-01-5','2016-01-4'], \
                   'counts': ['2', '1','1','1', '3','1']})

df1.date = pd.to_datetime(df1.date)
df1
  counts       date location
0      2 2016-01-01      lt1
1      1 2016-01-02      lt3
2      1 2016-01-01      lt6
3      2 2016-01-03      lt1
4      3 2016-01-05      lt2
5      1 2016-01-04      lt3
```

I want to put counts values depending on location from `df1` into `df`. The merge will be based on `date` column but the values to be added will be from `df2.counts` column and those values will be properly assigned into respective location names columns in `df`. Column names in `df` contains all the names present in `df1.location` column.

Merging just by date alone is easy but since it is not really a straightaway merge, it is more like reshaping or join. Any suggestion how to get the following df as output:

```
df
        date  lt1  lt2  lt3  lt4  lt5  lt6
0 2016-01-01    2    0    0    0    0    1
1 2016-02-01    0    0    1    0    0    0
2 2016-03-01    1    0    0    0    0    0
3 2016-04-01    0    0    1    0    0    0
4 2016-05-01    0    3    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
m=df1.pivot_table(index='date',columns='location',values='counts',aggfunc='sum')
final=df.set_index('date').combine_first(m).fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Or just:

```
(df.set_index('date').combine_first(df1.pivot('date','location','counts'))
                                             .fillna(0).reset_index())
```

---

```
        date lt1 lt2 lt3  lt4  lt5 lt6
0 2016-01-01   2   0   0    0    0   1
1 2016-01-02   0   0   1    0    0   0
2 2016-01-03   1   0   0    0    0   0
3 2016-01-04   0   0   1    0    0   0
4 2016-01-05   0   3   0    0    0   0
```

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: hey may be naive but what does aggfunc sum does in this case.. ?

Comment: @iamklaus nothing much,  just incase one has duplicate entries, it will help them sum per date. :) (thats what I thought, doesnt matter here in this context)

Comment: @iamklaus added one with plain `pivot`